# SQL How to Handle Subcategories

Tags: mysql, sql

Newbie here, so hopefully this isn't too dumb of a question.  I have a table of lab samples in a SQL database.  It includes Sample_IDs, Test_Names, Subtest_Names, and Results.  My current simple SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT Sample, Test, Subtest, Result
    FROM table
WHERE Sample = 'list of sample #s'
```

And this gives the following result:

```
SAMPLE  TEST    SUBTEST   RESULT
XX01    Test1   Test1Sub1   1
XX02    Test1   Test1Sub1   2
XX03    Test1   Test1Sub1   3
XX03    Test2   Test2Sub1   4
XX03    Test3   Test3Sub1   5
XX03    Test3   Test3Sub2   6
XX03    Test3   Test3Sub3   7
XX03    Test4   Test4Sub1   8
XX03    Test4   Test4Sub2   9
XX03    Test4   Test4Sub3   10
```

However, I am looking for the table to list by unique Sample_ID and list the Subtests as columns.  I know the names of the Subtests I am looking for so I can specify in the query.  For example, I would like the result above to instead look like:

```
    Test1Sub1   Test2Sub1   Test3Sub1   Test3Sub2   Test3Sub3   Test4Sub1   Test4Sub2   Test4Sub3
XX01    1                           
XX02    2                           
XX03    3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10
```

Can someone help me with the SQL code?  I did some searhing but am not knowledgable enough yet to be specific enough to find the answer I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: is the number of subtests (8 in this example) fixed?

Comment: @koenig26 is your environment SQL Server?

Comment: @zaggler I'm not sure removing the MySQL tag is the correct thing to do here. The OP tagged it with that database.

Comment: @bluefeet -- what happened -- you are no longer the king of pivot queries?

Comment: @bluefeet He may have tagged it `MySQL`, but none of his question even mentions it, ***except SQL*** which would be relevant... He just tagged an irrelevant tag and or OP is confused and does not know that `SQL` and `MySQL` are indeed different. I feel that the irrelevant tag should be removed as it's not mentioned in the OP's post at all...

Comment: @Zaggler SQL is the procedural language used in the MySQL database, removing the tag isn't appropriate.  Unless the OP states that they are not using MySQL, you have to assume they are based on the tags.

Comment: Good point, do people typically say I need help with using SQL in MySQL or do they state the obvious? The point is the standard I have seen is SQL is `SQL` and MySQL is `MySQL`... There's no confusion at this point correct, they both use SQL...

Comment: @Zaggler Yes, they do say SQL when referencing MySQL because the SQL is the language used in MySQL.

Comment: Yes they do what? Saying that people say they need help with SQL in MySQL I am confused... My point is if a user says SQL, around here it means SQL, not the other (MySQL). We have all seen it... Beside they do use the same language of course, but you don't have people saying I need help with SQL in MySQL...

Comment: @Zaggler My point is that OP tagged it with MySQL so removing it is inappropriate because that changes any syntax that would be used to answer the question.

Comment: @bluefeet good point, thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(SAMPLE VARCHAR(100),  TEST VARCHAR(100),    SUBTEST VARCHAR(100),   RESULT INT)
INSERT INTO #TEST 
VALUES
('XX01','Test1','Test1Sub1',   1   ),
('XX02','Test1','Test1Sub1',   2   ),
('XX03','Test1','Test1Sub1',   3   ),
('XX03','Test2','Test2Sub1',   4   ),
('XX03','Test3','Test3Sub1',   5   ),
('XX03','Test3','Test3Sub2',   6   ),
('XX03','Test3','Test3Sub3',   7   ),
('XX03','Test4','Test4Sub1',   8   ),
('XX03','Test4','Test4Sub2',   9   ),
('XX03','Test4','Test4Sub3',   10 )


SELECT *
FROM 
 (
    SELECT SAMPLE,RESULT,SUBTEST
           FROM  #Test        
) as s
PIVOT
(
    MAX(RESULT)
    FOR SUBTEST IN
(
Test1Sub1,
Test2Sub1,
Test3Sub1,
Test3Sub2,
Test3Sub3,
Test4Sub1,
Test4Sub2,
Test4Sub3
)
)AS pvt
```

[image]

Comment: MySQL does not have pivot function

Comment: @P.Salmon  He said SQL Databases so i thought.  Sorry

Comment: @P.Salmon just because he tagged `MySQL` does ***not*** mean he is using it. If you read his first paragraph ***nothing mentions MySQL***, its all ***SQL***; sad to say you are wrong... +1 for solution...

Comment: @Zaggler I agree!

Comment: @developer I edited the OPs question, removed ***non-relevant*** tags to avoid confusion. To many people ***jumping the gun without reading***... IMO please edit your answer to include what it does as the OP may not understand your solution, this also helps others that may come along and find your answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with left joins instead of pivot

```
select base.sample, 
       sum(t1s1.result) as Test1Sub1,
       sum(t2s1.result) as Test2Sub1,
       sum(t3s1.result) as Test3Sub1,
       sum(t4s1.result) as Test4Sub1,
       sum(t4s2.result) as Test4Sub2,
       sum(t4s3.result) as Test4Sub3
from (select distinct sample from tablename) as base
left join tablename t1s1 on base.sample = t1s1.sample and t1s1.subtest='Test1Sub1'
left join tablename t2s1 on base.sample = t2s1.sample and t2s1.subtest='Test2Sub1'
left join tablename t3s1 on base.sample = t3s1.sample and t3s1.subtest='Test3Sub1'
left join tablename t4s1 on base.sample = t4s1.sample and t4s1.subtest='Test4Sub1'
left join tablename t4s2 on base.sample = t4s2.sample and t4s2.subtest='Test4Sub2'
left join tablename t4s3 on base.sample = t4s3.sample and t4s3.subtest='Test4Sub3'
group by sample
```

> you can use max() instead of sum() -- I'm guessing you actually want sum.